# bootstrap switch checked status always returns true

Tags: bootstrap-switch

```
 if ($("#Switch").is(":checked") == true)
 {
 alert("checked");
 }
 else
 {
 alert(" Not checked");
 }
```

This code is giving me the alert "checked" first time after changing the switch state from OFF to ON. And after i am changing the state to OFF again but it is showing only alert "checked".
Please help me, I am using this code in button click event. Every time I am getting only checked.

Answer (score 1):

```
    function getChecked(elementId)
    {
    if ($("#elementId").is(":checked") == true)
     {
     alert("checked");
     }
     else
     {
     alert(" Not checked");
     }
    }

onchange="getChecked('#id')"
```

Answer (score 0):

put this code inside your js onchange event

```
var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
if(checked) {
  alert('checked');
} else {
  alert('not checked');
}
```